# NIS failing on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos-6

**Solved: See bottom**. tl;dr: enable network manager.

I'm trying to set up a CentOS6 system to login using NIS. I've set up the NISDOMAIN and for the files like passwd to be on the NIS server in nsswitch.conf, but it fails to bind to the NIS server (it can ping it and SSH into it, so not a visibility issue), when booting or restarting ypbind, it waits for ages on Binding NIS service: ..... , then returns [  OK  ], but doesn't actually bind as far as I can tell.

When I try ypwhich, I get the following:

```
ypwhich: Can't communicate with ypbind
```

Looking around suggests that it might not be running when people have this problem, but it seems to be for me, at least as far as service and chkconfig show.

```
rpcinfo -u localhost ypbind
```

returns the following:

```
rpcinfo: RPC: Program not registered
program 100007 is not available
```

Edit: typo and slight clarification.

Edit2: The NIS server is definitely specified, but it's acting as if it is not. When I do a

```
service ypbind restart
```

this is the output in /var/log/messages:

```
Mar  7 13:29:27 foobar dbus: avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=6)
Mar  7 13:29:27 foobar dbus: avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=6)
Mar  7 13:29:27 foobar dbus: avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=6)
Mar  7 13:29:27 foobar dbus: [system] Reloaded configuration
Mar  7 13:29:37 foobar ypbind: NIS domain: FOO, NIS server:
```

The server is definitely specified in yp.conf:

```
domain FOO server 192.168.1.xxx
```

Yet messages doesn't show this address.

Edit3: **Solution:**
It turns out ypbind will only work with network manager controlling the interface on CentOS6. Kind of a kludge, but it works - just enable network manager on the interface. When that's done, just restart ypbind and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check to see if you have Firewall enabled which will likely stop the communication between the NIS client and the NIS server.

```
chkconfig --list | grep iptables
```

Try the following:

```
service iptables stop
```

Then re-try your client binding.

If that fixes the connectivity problem, then you can either turn off `iptables` (Firewall) or modify the rules appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, and for me it was the `NetworkManager` that was the problem

i.e.

```
service NetworkManager stop
chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

Then also make sure that each of the interfaces is not controlled by NetworkManager , and add `NM_CONTROLLED=no`, i.e. I ran the following command

```
sed -i -e 's/\(^NM_CONTROLLED=\).*/\1no/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*
```

Comment: OP solved it by _enabling_ NetworkManager (in my experience, that is the way to solve such problems), and you propose disabling it for good. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on rhel 7.9:

On my slave server:

```
[root@rhel79nisslaver ~]# /usr/lib64/yp/ypinit -s 192.x.x.x
Can't enumerate maps from 192.x.x.x. Please check that it is running.


[root@rhel79nisslaver ~]# /usr/bin/ypwhich
ypwhich: Can't communicate with ypbind
```

Solution for me: Stop firewalls service on the master server:

```
# systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

Another solution is to add it to the trusted zone in firewalls; all traffic from that IP address will be allowed. See the example below on  the NIS master:

```
[root@rhel79nis ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.x.x.x --permanent 

[root@rhel79nis ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Hope this can help :)